# Valgrind: Can an increasing number of possibly lost bytes be aceppted?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am developing a C ++ application that reads inputs and acts on some
engines, sending information to another device.

The main program remains in an infinite loop repeating the same process every
5 seconds.

I am analyzing said application with Valgrind and it shows the following results:

```
==4453== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 8
. . .
==4453== 106 byt4es in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 7 of 8
. . .
==4453== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4453==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4453==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4453==      possibly lost: 148 bytes in 2 blocks
==4453==    still reachable: 2,310 bytes in 8 blocks
==4453==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

If I let the number of iterations the program performs in the infinite loop increase, the number of bytes in the "possibly lost" category remains the same, but the number of bytes in the "still reachable" category increases proportionally to the number of iterations performed (each time the program repeats the instructions contained in the loop, the number of still reachable bytes increases).

I have the following questions regarding this:

- Are the bytes in the still reachable category really memory leaks?
- Would it be permissible for the number of still reachable bytes to increase with the time the program is running or should this be solved?

Comment: I relay recommend you to use address sanitizer. It was introduced by clang, then gcc implemented it and now even msvc has own prototype of it. It works faster is more reliable and reports are more readable (at least for me).

Comment: They are not leaks in the sense that you could free them if you chose to, they are leaks in the sense that you don't. -- Yes, if I were your manager, FWIW, I would demand that this be fixed.

Comment: "still reachable" means that somewhere in the program is a pointer to that memory. So the program can free it correctly if it wants to. The definitely lost means that all of the pointers were overwritten and freeing the memory is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes the "still reachable" bytes are memory leaks.

If your program runs constantly eventually the system will run out of memory and crash.

### It should be solved.

It should be solved because of the eventual crash.

Alternatively in very complicated programs people have just given up, and they put in monitoring or a timer and just restart the program every hour. This is silly, but sometimes a stupid solution is the cheapest fastest one. Cheap, fast, good: pick two.

### Solving this should be trivial.

I wrote a memory leak program and ran it. Look a few lines down from the top where it says `operator new[]` and then `main (leak-test.cpp:7)`. Valgrind pinpoints the allocation for you.

```
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./leak-test
==929671==
==929671== HEAP SUMMARY:
==929671==     in use at exit: 8,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==929671==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 81,728 bytes allocated
==929671==
==929671== 8,000 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==929671==    at 0x4095504: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:431)
==929671==    by 0x100009F7: main (leak-test.cpp:7)
==929671==
==929671== LEAK SUMMARY:
==929671==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==929671==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==929671==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==929671==    still reachable: 8,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==929671==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==929671==
==929671== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==929671== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```